# Can Polly rate limiting be used when scaling out

Tags: rate-limiting, polly

We have a service that handles integrations with our various partners. An integration may involve calling an api. One such api could have a rate limit ie no more than 10 requests in 60 seconds. From what I have read Polly can handle this with the Rate Limit policy.

Would this work in a scenario where you have multiple instances of the service running?

Comment: No it won't work. [Rate limiter](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Rate-Limit) can be shared between multiple requests but not between multiple service instances. For the latter case you might need to use a service mesh, like [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/).

Comment: I'm working on something that aims to handle these types of cases here: https://hallpass.dev/ ... looking for testers (it's very early stage) and would love your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot) to implement rate limiting. You'll need a single instance that all your service instances will call into.